# STL Container constructed from other container (e.g. list from vector)

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, constructor, iterator

In my code, sometimes I need to construct a container from another container. But these container objects are of different types, so I can't use a copy constructor. What I do looks like this (C++11, I use uniform initialization and constructor delegation) :

```
std::vector<int> source {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
std::list<int> destination (source.begin (), source.end ());
```

I realized that std::list could have a constructor like this, to make things prettier:

```
template </* ... */>
class list
{
public:
    template <class Container> list (const Container& container)
    : list (container.begin (), container.end ())
    {
    }

    /* ... */
};
```

Unfortunately I can do this only for my own classes, not for STL classes. So first question, of there a reason such costructors don't exist in STL and Boost? And second question, is there a safe way to implement such a ctor for STL containers, maybe by defining conversion operators somehow?

This issue os of course just a matter of convenience, nothing critical to code or to program behavior. But it could make the code look a bit more readable:

```
std::vector<int> source {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
std::list<int> destination = source;
```

Comment: My personal impression is (I have no sources for this) that the design committee consciously chose iterator ranges as the main abstraction for standard library containers - and honestly, they work quite well and are flexible. The addition of the constructor you describe would make the standard library larger and more complex, for *minimal* benefit. The very common case where iterator ranges made code less readable has been fixed in C++11 by introducing the `for (int i : myintvector)` construction.

Comment: I also feel very strongly that modifying the standard library to save a few characters in code is *not* a good tradeoff in terms of maintainability!

Comment: It exists boost ranges. Algorithms takes a range ( constructed from containers, may be transform with adapters and things like that ). It exists proposals to add ranges to the standard library, but there is no consensus yet, and it is considered low priority

Comment: Sometimes "source" is a long expression, and then repeating it twice creates a long ugly line. In these cases, using the constructor I suggest (which adds just one simple inline contructor to each STL container) makes the line more readable. Imagine "source" would be replaced with something like model->tasks["participants"]

Comment: @us2012: Well, the standard C++ committee is working on integrating ranges into the standard C++ library. I _think_ a proposal to allow range based initialization along the lines of range-based `for` made it into C++14. When I say "the standard C++ committee" it is actually misleading: the work is really done by individuals and I haven't done as much as I should have to get ranges into C++17.

Comment: @galop1n: I don't think adding ranges to the standard C++ library is considered low priority but doing it properly is unfortunately a lot more work than just stating the goal.

Comment: @Dietmar-Kuhl I heard it from a recent Herb Sutter's talk. We can say that he is a relevant source of information. I will try to find where exactly i heard it and link on this topic.

Comment: @galop1n: It is great that Herb doesn't consider it a priority. However, others do consider it a priority and Herb's opinion only matters so much. Since I, at least, attend the Ranges Study group sessions I have a first hand idea of what is going on there. I haven't seen Herb attend the ranges study group sessions so far.

Comment: @fr33domlover: add this support is error prone, and will result low performance program. Let's say you are using vector as an function type for a complex function, then you want change to list, and you forget to change one tmpVar type for 'return tmpVar' inside the function, you didn't get compile error.

Comment: Is there a reason it's not there? Well, yes, it's unneccessary since iterators already provide the functionality yet with a much bigger flexibility. In the same way you could ask why there aren't standard algorithms that take containers directly. Though the ranges (simply said a generalization of containers) that will some day find their way into the standard are a movement into that direction and it might be that we'll then see range-constructors for containers, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be suspicious of code where the complete range of one container type is copied to another. This is an uncommon activity.

In C++, explicit conversions are usually preferred. Implicit conversions and assignment operators that convert from one type to another are usually discouraged because they sometimes lead to unexpected conversions.

If you truly need to frequently convert between container types, try defining an explicit helper function for the conversion:

```
template<typename ToType, typename FromType>
ToType container_cast(const FromType& source)
{
    return ToType(source.begin(), source.end(), source.get_allocator());
}
```

Then your example becomes:

```
std::vector<int> source {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
auto destination = container_cast<std::list<int> >(source);
```

Comment: In this case I prefer to use the existing begin/end constructor, because container_cast is unfamiliar and not standard and may scare people. But it's probably a good alternative in cases it makes the code more readable.

Comment: There would probably be some merit to a helper function if you also needed to copy the allocator.

Comment: I think that covertly copying the allocator is more dubious than converting the container type -- if someone has supplied a specific allocator to a specific container then one should think hard before using it for another container, not just let it happen by default. Anyway, if the only argument against a proposed constructor is that it would allow suprising implicit conversions then the appropriate response is an explicit constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proposal in c++14 that, if I'm not wrong, would enable to pass another container as a "traversable" directly to a container's constructor.

The latest revision of the proposal can be found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3763.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that letting a container be instantiated from anything iterable leads to a lot of unexpected behaviour and ambiguities. For example:

```
auto mystring = std::string { "ABC" };
auto mylist = std::list { mystring };
```

Shall `mylist` be instantiated here as a list of strings with just one element (as is currently the case with C++17), or as a list of the three characters 'A', 'B' and 'C', as would be the case in the iterable unrolling? Making the unrolling explicit solves that problem neatly, even, if it is a bit tedious to write.